# Java - Scanner can't find symbol

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read every word (from every line) from a file which is sent in through args.

It's just a simple text file:

```
aa bb cc d
dd ee f gg
xx yy zz
```

The scanner seems to not be able to find the scanner symbol..
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Args
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> wordArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        File filename = new File(args[0]);

        if (args.length == 1)
        {


            try
            {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine())
                {
                    while (scanner.hasNext())
                    {
                        wordArrayList.add(scanner.Next());

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Oops, file "+ filename + "not found.");
            }


        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Nothing to do.. Powering down..");
        }
    }
}
```

Does any1 know what I am doing wrong with the scanner here?

This is the Error code:

```
Args.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        wordArrayList.add(scanner.Next());
                                                 ^
  symbol:   method Next()
  location: variable scanner of type Scanner
1 error
```

Comment: it should be `scanner.next()` not `scanner.Next()`

Comment: Method names are case sensitive.

Comment: This seems to be working, however the scanner only reads every 2nd word from the file.

Comment: code seems fine , make sure data and file name is valid

Answer (score 0):

Because in java methods name are case sensitive you should check how your method is named.

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html your method is named `next()` not `Next()`.

Changing it to `next()` should fix the problem.